# Spring Security CSRF support for manual security configuration

Tags: java, spring-security, csrf

I am dealing with a complex manual security configuration (Spring 3.4, Spring Security 3.2).  The filter chains have been configured manually with `httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter` and other beans configured by us.

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant" request-matcher="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter, ... beans ...,filterInvocationInterceptor"/>
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

Now, I need to add CSRF protection.  I cannot add http and csrf tags, as http is duplicating the manual config.  Instead, I tried to configure this in Java, but the Java config does not add CSRF filter.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
}
```

I declared the bean `<bean class="package.WebSecurityConfig"/>` in application context, yet WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure method is never called on app context creation.

How can I add CSRF protection here?  Do I need to insert CSRFFilter manually as well?

Answer (score 0):

Extract from this [link](http://patrickgrimard.com/2014/01/03/spring-security-csrf-protection-in-a-backbone-single-page-app/) if its answers your question.

```
import my.filter.CsrfTokenGeneratorFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenGeneratorFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        }

}

/**
 * Filter which adds CSRF information as response headers.
 *
 * @author Patrick Grimard
 * @since 12/31/2013 4:48 PM
 */
public final class CsrfTokenGeneratorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf");

        // Spring Security will allow the Token to be included in this header name
        response.setHeader("X-CSRF-HEADER", token.getHeaderName());

        // Spring Security will allow the token to be included in this parameter name
        response.setHeader("X-CSRF-PARAM", token.getParameterName());

        // this is the value of the token to be included as either a header or an HTTP parameter
        response.setHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", token.getToken());

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```